# Why is the Android activity weirdly zoomed in?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am running the app on Galaxy Note, which is hdpi. And I got all the drawables (drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi etc.) correct. But the page (activity) is weirdly zoomed in like this:

[image]

You can notice that the cursor icon, top header and the background tiles are larger than normal.

It is supposed to be like this:

[image]

The layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_app"
    >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
        android:minLines="3"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved by using

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: It would have been great if you've told us what you changed exactly in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: he actually did, but Stackoverflow hide the tags^^

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following to the manifest
the tag "uses-sdk" with android:minSdkVersion="8" (it might work with 7 I did not test)
:-)